# Am I too critical in reviewing suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Since recently I am able to review suggested edits on SO. I enjoy doing it, however I noticed that I often reject edits which are approved in the end. So I am wondering if I am either too harsh and should change my voting behavior or others simply have an easier time to approve edits.

See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4510798 as an example: This seems to me like an invalid edit as this new tag does not exist and the question clearly aims at C++, so the tag seems appropriate to me.

More often I reject edits because they are too minor (at least in my opinion), take this as example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4506077. The only thing improved is the correct version of the tag (and I do not even consider the zend-framework tag as incorrect), but there are lots of typos and spelling mistakes left in the question.

Or take this https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4506099 as example. It is not only minor, I also think it is plain wrong. The new formatting doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Overall, you don't seem too harsh. I'm not familiar with C++, so I skipped that review. Your second example doesn't add anything, and it's clear that they're talking about Zend Framework 2. Also, the edit removed the general Zend Framework tag, which could make the question more difficult to find. Your third example is a blatant misuse of formatting, and rejecting that was appropriate.

Comment: I definitely would have rejected the 3rd example (and checked the user that did it to see if there's a pattern of that kind of edit), and likely would have rejected the first as well for the same reason as you. Though I often wonder if I'm too harsh as well...

Comment: You're not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and hints (and the feeling that I am not alone on this one). And especially thanks at @Qantas94Heavy as I didn't even now the data tool up to now and it looks awesome (and how could I miss that the whole time?). I think I can safely go back to reviewing without feeling like I do something wrong.

Comment: For some reason the comment disappeared... If anyone needs it: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120358/most-suggested-edits-that-have-been-rejected-by-reviewers

Comment: Welcome to the club.

Comment: No, you're part of the solution. The other reviews are the problem.